# On the back-uping of python script

Tags: python, linux, backup

Occasionally working with my python script I've closed non-saved script.py file and part of my script was lost. Taking into account that I still have loaded within the shell python where the full script has been loaded. IS it possible to restore full script?

Thanks for help,

Gleb

Comment: If it's in the shell why don't you just save it again?

Comment: because last time the version of the script without first part has been launched :) is it possible to same python file in the separate *.py from the python interpreter console ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the normal python debugger, you can:

```
>>> l 1, 100000
<...contents of the file...>
```

Comment: >>> l 1, 100000
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    l 1, 100000
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax